# WatchOS Complication displayName not showing

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

The complication displayName show blank or app name.

[Showing Blank Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRj9l.png)

I implemented complication from widgetKit.

And I set configurationDisplayName, description.

But the displayName show blank or app name.

The complication that I selected is working well. But it's display name on the selected list is blank. It's only problem.

How I can show display name as I want?

Answer (score 1):

Wow... I set the WidgetConfiguration to IntentConfiguration.

I changed it to  StaticConfiguration.

It is solved. Good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).